# Uncertainty Calculation Problems

Tags: analysis

I am having difficulty solving these Uncertainty Calculation Problems. If someone could show me how to do them so I know, that would be great. I will include the answer with each of the 3 questions, I just don't know how to get to the answer.

Thank you!

**Question 1:** 
A digital multimeter is used to measure the resistance and current through a resistor at $120.8 \Omega$ (Ohms) and $0.05 A$, respectively. The uncertainty in both of these measurements has been previously determined to be $\pm 0.3 \Omega$ and $\pm 0.001 A$, respectively. Determine the uncertainty in the power dissipated by the resistor using the equation: 
$$P = I^2 R$$

Answer: $0.01210$

**Question 2 :**
The force generated from the rodless chamber in a pneumatic cylinder is given as: 
$$f = \frac{\pi}{4}d^2 p$$ 
where $d$ is the diameter of the cylinder bore and $p$ is the chamber pressure. The cylinder pressure is measured at $105 psia$ with an uncertainty of $\pm 0.8 psia$. The cylinder diameter is given from the cylinder manufacturer to be $2.2\pm 0.006 inch$. Determine the uncertainty in the generated force.

Answer: $3.7400$

**Question 3:**
The potential energy of a compressed spring is: 
$$U = \frac{1}{2}kx^2$$ 
where $k$ is the spring constant and $x$ is the length of spring deflection. The spring constant is known to be $201\pm 7$ Newtons per meter. The spring deflection has been measured to be $0.11\pm 0.004$ meters. Determine the uncertainty in the potential energy of the deflected spring.

Answer: $0.0981$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE :) Please tell us what you tried so far, which ideas you had and where you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of uncertainty calculation is very close to the problem of derivatives. Let me take a simple case where $Y = 2 X$ and we know that the uncertainty in $X$ is $0.1$. Suppose that the mleasured value of $X$ is 10.0; plot $Y$ as a function of $X$ and you know that $X$ is is fact between $9.9$ and $10.1$ because of the $0.1$ uncertainty. Looking at the corresponding range for $Y$, you will notice that $19.8<Y<20.2$. SO the uncertainty for $Y$ is $0.2$ that is to say twice larger than the uncertainty for $X$. Think now about derivatives : $Y=2X$ implies $\frac{\text{dY}}{dX}=2$ what we can rewrite as $dY=2 dX$. Here, now, we make a jump saying that $dX$ is not infinitesimal and we replace $dX$ by $\Delta X$ and $dY$ by $\Delta Y$.

So, in other words, when you have $Y=f(X)$ and you know the uncertainty for $X$, the uncertainty for $Y$ is just given, from $\frac{\text{dY}}{dX}=f'(x)$, by $$\Delta Y=f'(X) \Delta X$$. Hoping that this is clear, let us take a more complex problem where $Z=f(X,Y)$. The same approach is made for one variable at the time and,as a result, we so arrive to the fact that the uncertainty for $Z$ is given by the derivative of $$\Delta Z=\frac{\text{dZ}}{dX} \Delta X+\frac{\text{dZ}}{dY} \Delta Y$$ In fact, since we do not know the sign of the errors, absolute values must be used for each term on the right hand side.

So, let us consider yout first problem which is $P = I^2 R$. Computing the derivatives, they are $2I R$ (with respect to $I$) and $I^2$ (with respect to $R$), for $I=0.05$ and $R=120.8$, then these derivatives are respectively $12.08$ and $0.0025$. So, $$\Delta P=12.08 \Delta I + 0.0025 \Delta R$$ Replace $\Delta I$ by $0.001$ and $\Delta R$ by $0.3$ to get $\Delta P=0.01208+0.00075=0.01283$ ... which does not match your answer.

I hope and wish this clarifies something. Let me know if you want to clarify anything. I also could tell you about useful recipes using logarithmic differentiation related to calculation of uncertainties. Just let me know.